# break; does not work properly

Tags: php, break

I have this code:

```
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {  

    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $text) !== false) {
            array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value"=>strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if ( count($result) > 2 )
        break;              
}
```

The break statement does not work so I get more than 2 items.
However if I change the break; to

```
die('results more than 2');
```

it shows that it's working properly.

Am I using the break statement correctly?

Comment: How many more then two? Because from looking at it, I would expect $result to contain 3 items. Yes, you are using the break correctly.

Comment: Your current code will break when `$result` contains 3 or more itens (`> 2`). Do you want it to break with exactly 2? Then use `== 2` or `> 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you get more than 2 items. You said `if count($result) > 2` and not `>= 2`
So when you have more than 2 results, it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you `break` with `if ( count($result) > 2 )` then of course you'll have more than 2 items.
If you want only two, just use `if ( count($result) >= 2 )`

Answer (score 1):

Apply it and test the result :

```
if ( count($result) >= 2 ) break;
```